# Why the tuple-type list element's value cannot be modified?

Tags: c#

In C# 8.0, I can modify the value inside a tuple directly by accessing the field name:

```
(string name, int score) student = ("Tom", 100);
student.name = "Jack";
Console.WriteLine(student);
```

And I can modify the list element's property as follow:

```
var list = new List<Student>();  // assume I have a Student class which has a Name property
list.Add(new Student { Name = "Tom" });
list[0].Name = "Jack";
Console.WriteLine(list[0]);
```

But why can't I modify the tuple-type element's value like this?

```
var list = new List<(string name, int score)>();
list.Add(("Tom", 100));
list[0].name = "Jack"; // Error!
Console.WriteLine(list[0]);
```

Comment: Because tuples are structs and you get a copy of the original value, so modifying would be on the copy not on the original value. The compiler prevents you from doing something that wouldn't work in the first place

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A tuple (`ValueTuple`) is a struct. Rather than returning a *reference* to the value as is the case with your `Student` example, you would actually recieve a **copy** of the tuple.

Changes to that copy wouldn't be reflected in the list and would be discarded. The compiler is smart enough to recognize this and stops you from doing it.

If it *did* compile, it would be to something *similar* to the following:

```cs
var list = new List<(string name, int score)>(); list.Add(("Tom", 100));
var copy = list[0];
copy.name = "Jack"; 
Console.WriteLine(copy.name);    // Jack
Console.WriteLine(list[0].name); // still Tom
```

Mutable structs can be dangerous if you don't use them properly. The compiler is simply doing its job.

You can work around this with the following:

```cs
var list = new List<(string name, int score)>(); list.Add(("Tom", 100));
var copy = list[0];
copy.name = "Jack"; 
list[0] = copy;                  // put it back
Console.WriteLine(copy.name);    // Jack
Console.WriteLine(list[0].name); // Jack
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##bY4xC8IwEIX3/oqjUwI1rXNUkA5C6abgIA41PeSwTUoSlf76mpTiII733sf3TrmVcjRNr8ZCR87DFjS@4Tg6j70oTdeh8mS0EwfUaEmJOlAb5rwlfQfd9JgBaQ9OGYt8x7icPWLftoylJ9OnGayLgnOZxA1lhjFsRORSXGUSbxEtIUyrRj1SCcnShijWEvIchqcH8nALRFKGd0yH4mzJY00a2dfCZ7j6Ty3aH3CaPg)

If you use an array `(string, int)[]` instead of a `List<(string, int)>`, this isn't a problem due to the way array element access works:

```cs
var arr = new (string name, int score) [] { ( "Tom", 10 ) };
arr[0].name = "Jack";
Console.WriteLine(arr[0].name); // Jack
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##JcwxC8IwEIbhvb/iI1MCtdQ5OLmJo9ChdAjhkEN7gbugg/S3x4r7877ZDtm4tVdSJFWcIPSGt6osd0haqQdLheWiFDAv@MDD3crqehxHBGyx28N5XIaf3gfukvLDxe5cxMqThkm50pWF/N@F2NoX)

This behavior is not unique to `List` or your tuple type. You'll experience this issue with any collection where the element is a Value Type (unless of course they offer a `ref` element accessor).

Note that there are similar issues when having a `readonly` field of a **mutable** value type that mutates via method calls. This can be much more **insidious** as no error or warning is emitted:

```cs
struct MutableStruct { 
   public int Val; 
   public void Mutate(int newVal) {
     Val = newVal;
   } 
} 
class Test {
    private readonly MutableStruct msReadonly;
    private MutableStruct msNormal;
    public Test() {
      msNormal = msReadonly = new MutableStruct(){ Val=5 };
    } 
    public void MutateReadonly() {
         Console.WriteLine(msReadonly.Val); // 5
         msReadonly.Mutate(66);             // defensive copy! 
         Console.WriteLine(msReadonly.Val); // still 5!!! 
    } 
    public void MutateNormal() {
         Console.WriteLine(msNormal.Val);   // 5
         msNormal.Mutate(66);
         Console.WriteLine(msNormal.Val);   // 66
    } 
}
new Test().MutateReadonly();
new Test().MutateNormal();
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##lVGxboMwEN35imMjQ8kEi5Wpa9uhrdqZmKtkybGRz1BFiG@ndm2CQxVVsbz43rv33p05PXAS80zW9NzCc2@bo8S38BohA4CuP0rBQSgLH41kaW3Qov3tsVh4XOG3o@xg9BzwdDjEIvOlCTJ3uWyI4B3JRmJnxOAkwGDTaiXPmxgneo0Au6JvWS/anKLREtCbFJc8F45LtYqGiNdqxW706Q8VTEFvglQ2mXtRSVzcedSKtMTy0wiLT0JhsfqVfkUM9nuo1oYEjvus60Bq8QsViQGB6@6cw70mZIWUUOV5bL05SVjN/3ME3o0pIpjMcJ9YXS8hp8z/SvjAcrtr9hdc4rN5/gE)

`ValueTuple` is a great addition to the framework and language. But there's a reason you'll often hear that `[Mutable] structs are evil.` In the majority of cases you shouldn't hit these restrictions. If you find yourself falling into this pattern a lot, I suggest moving over to a `record`, which is a reference type (thus not suffering these issues) and can be reduced to a tuple-like syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Mutable value types are evil, it's hard to see why this prints "Tom" not "Jack":

```
(string name, int score) student = ("Tom", 100);
(string name, int score) student2 = student;
student.name = "Jack";
Console.WriteLine(student2);
```

The reason is that you always create a copy. Because it's not obvious you should avoid mutable value types. To avoid that people will fall into that trap the compiler just allows to modify the object directly via properties(like above). But if you try to do it via a method call you get a compiler error "Cannot modify the return value of ... because it is not a variable".

So this is not allowed:

```
list[0].name = "Jack";
```

It would create a new copy of the `ValueTuple`, assigns a value but doesn't use or store it anywhere.

This compiles because you assign it to a new variable and modify it via property:

```
(string name, int score) x = list[0];
x.name = "Jack"; // Compiles
```

So it compiles but gives you again a suprising result:

```
Console.WriteLine(list[0]);  // Tom
```

Read more about it here: [Do Not Define Mutable Value Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/june/csharp-tuple-trouble-why-csharp-tuples-get-to-break-the-guidelines#do-not-define-mutable-value-types)

Comment: I spent a while typing my answer on mobile and by the time I was done you had posted yours. I've kept my answer, but have an upvote

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: thanks, OP accepted the right answer